# loopback Add non static remote method error

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I am trying to add a non-static remote method to a model. Just follow the [code](https://gist.github.com/pulkitsinghal/3eeaec87d536a822ee0c) here. Unfortunately, I got some error message.

The following is my code

```
User.prototype.lastOrder = function(callback){
  console.log('print this instance object: ', this);
  callback(null)
};

User.remoteMethod('__get__lastOrder', {
  isStatic: false,
  accepts: [],
  description: 'Get the latest order of the user',
  http: {
    path: '/lastOrder',
    verb: 'get'
}
```

And when I invoke `http://localhost:3000/v1/users/1/lastOrder`. it gives me the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to remoteMethod is the function name. What you have defined isn't valid. You need to define a function called, well, let's say lastOrder, and then modify your code like so:

```
User.prototype.lastOrder = function() {

}

User.remoteMethod('lastOrder', {
  isStatic:false,
  //more stuff here
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried in this way, still the same error.

Comment: See my comment below. You posted a new answer. Is that what worked for you?

Answer (score 3):

```
  User.prototype.lastOrder = function(callback){
    console.log('print this instance object: ', this);
    callback(null, "this is a test");
  };

  User.remoteMethod('lastOrder', {  // should be lastOrder not __get__lastOrder
    isStatic: false,
    accepts: [],
    description: 'Get the latest order of the user',
    http: {
      path: '/lastOrder',
      verb: 'get',
      status: 200
    },
    returns: {root: true, type: 'order'}
  });
```

Comment: @RaymondCamden. Yes.  It is a static method, so it should be `User.prototype.lastOrder`.  I thought you made a typo, so I post the all correct answer, just want to avoid of misleading others. Anyway, I will accept your answer, but I will correct your answer.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I could have sworn the docs said to use Model.NAME for all cases, even non-static, but it makes sense that it would be under prototype.

Comment: @RaymondCamden, could you plz peer view my edit on your answer. add 'prototype' on the definition.

Comment: I'm going to double check that you are right in the morning. I just don't believe it. No offense - I'm still learning myself and I need to see this in action to believe it. :)

Comment: Hello, @RaymondCamden.  [Remote Methods](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/Remote+methods), and go to the `options` sections. It is mentioned in the `isStatic` keyword. `Boolean. Whether the method is static (eg. MyModel.myMethod). Use false to define the method on the prototype (for example, MyModel.prototype.myMethod). Default is true.`

Comment: Ah - I was looking at the text around "accepts" - which did not mention. I'm sorry I 'fought' you so much on this, I just wanted to be really sure.

Comment: As an FYI, I was not able to accept your edit. But I was able to make the edit myself.